# How to use jquery in grails

Tags: jquery, grails

I want to have a field date field ,on clicking it displays calendar(jquery datepicker) and the format should be "dd-mm-yy" and it should be editable.how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Including jquery and jqueryui (there are plugins for both or 2.0.0M1 comes with jquery now yet you still will be needing jquery ui)

You can make a js file containing this and include it as well ;

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
"dateFormat": "dd-mm-y"});
```

or if you want to do it within GSP, you can use

```
<g:javascript>
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      "dateFormat": "dd-mm-y"});
</g:javascript>
```

Answer (score 2):

Include the jQuery and jQuery UI then:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    "dateFormat": "dd-mm-y"
});
```

It's editable by default.